# Kotlin SharedFlow and catching Exceptions

Tags: android, kotlin-flow

I am on an Android project using Kotlin and Flows.  My team wants to handle non-nominal cases by throwing exceptions.  If a class uses a MutableStateFlow, using it to expose a Flow, how can an exception be emitted to that MutableStateFlow so that the consumer can 'catch' and act on the exception?  (Is this approach even possible?)

For a code example.

```
method2().catch{
    // How can I catch an exception thrown from evaluateEnvStatus?
}.collect {
    // ....
}


val mutableSharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
suspend fun evaluateEnvStatus(){
    if(isEnvAcceptable){
        mutableSharedFlow.emit("Acceptable")
    else {
        // How can I throw an exception here that can be caught by someone consuming the SharedFlow?
    }
}

fun updateEnvStatus : Flow<String> {
    scope.launch(){
       method1()
    }
    return mutableSharedFlow
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "throw" an exception from `SharedFlow` because that would mean it completed and `SharedFlows` never end.

If you want to emit failure to collectors you have to instead expose a cold flow that transforms value of your shared flow and throws then.

For example:

```kotlin
private val _messageFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Result<String>>()
val messageFlow = _messageFlow.map { it.getOrThrow() }

// where you produce values:
private suspend fun evaluateEnvStatus(){
    if(isEnvAcceptable){
        _messageFlow.emit(Result.success("Acceptable"))
    } else {
        _messageFlow.emit(Result.failure(IllegalArgumentException("Unacceptable")))
    }
}

// collecting:
// to stop collecting on exception catch it
messageFlow
    .catch { exception ->  } // handle exception
    .collect { message -> } // String

// to keep collecting after exception, retry the cold flow *
messageFlow
    .retry { exception -> true } // handle exception and return true
    .collect { message -> } // String
```

Do note that retrying has a big caveat: even though you will restart the flow collection, any values emitted between exception and restart won't be handled and so will be values in buffer (if you enable it). So I would not actually recommend it for this case.

If you really need to collect all values I don't think there's a better solution to just emitting a wrapped error and parsing it on collector side without using any exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `catch` block directly to the sharedflow object. See the below example.

```
mutableSharedFlow
.catch { e -> emit("Error occurred") } 
.collect { event ->
    // Handle event
    mutableSharedFlow.emit("Acceptable")
}
```

Comment: From my testing this only works for exceptions thrown from inside of a cold flow.  Have you got it to work with a SharedFlow?